# What is to stop people from pumping the volume of transactions via automated micropayments to a large group of addresses?

Tags: buy-bitcoins, sell-bitcoins, volume

This depends on the way in which # transactions are measured.

Answer (score 4):

There's several anti-DOS measures that counter this:

- transaction fees get expensive with large numbers of outputs
- many rapid transactions with no fees will be rejected
- small amounts (less than 0.000045) in an output are called dust, and are rejected

It essentially becomes prohibitively expensive to try to spam.